# Any SharePoint tools to convert Server Object Model Code to Powershell

Tags: ssom, pnp-powershell

Is there any tool to convert the SharePoint server object model to PowerShell?

Comment: I don't think so there is any tool available which can convert SSOM to PowerShell Code.